# Error: texlive-scripts package not found (?!), skipping revision consistency check

Tags: errors, texlive, updating

Since few days ago, when I load the repository with TeX Live Shell, I've got:

```
texlive-scripts package not found (?!), skipping revision consistency check
```

When I update my TeX Live distribution, errors like this appear:

```
tlmgr.pl: updmap-sys failed (status 1), output:
C:\texlive\2023\bin\windows\runscript.tlu:941: C:\texlive\2023\bin\windows\runscript.tlu:864: no appropriate script or program found: updmap
```

However, the packages are updated and if I compile a document I have no problem.

Should I reinstall TeX Live 2023? Or may I wait till 2024?

Comment: I didn't see that yet (but I'm always using the command line to install), but the first thing I would try is `tlmgr install texlive-scripts`, and if the problem persists write to the texlive mailing list.

Comment: Thank you, @UlrikeFischer, I'll try.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer `tlmgr install texlive-scripts` works, I also wrote to le texlive mailing list because I first lauched it by mistake on Cygwin64 Terminal instead of Windows Command Prompt. Would you like to add an answer or should I delete the question?